# Request infomation from facebook account iOS

Tags: ios, facebook

I am making an app login feature with Facebook account. I have the Facebook `tokenkey` by running this command: `appDelegate.session.accessTokenData.accessToken`. Then I take `username` and `user_ID` like this:

```
FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForMe];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    if (error == nil) {
        // result is a dictionary with the user's Facebook data
        NSDictionary *userData = (NSDictionary *)result;

        NSString *facebookID = userData[@"id"];
        NSLog(@"facebookID  = %@",facebookID);
```

or

```
if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
    [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
     ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, 
       NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, 
       NSError *error) {
         if (!error) {
             self.userNameLabel.text = user.name;
             self.userProfileImage.profileID = user.id;
         }
     }];      
}
```

the result is the same and when I debug It always jump up in `if(!error)`.

Where does this error come from?

Comment: You sure those properties are yours? - `self.userNameLabel.text = user.name; self.userProfileImage.profileID = user.id;` And have you tried NSLogging the error?

Comment: Thank bro!I'm catch the error and solve it right now. I am begining so sometime I forget basic skill.